Rust book tutorial, slightly modified, not printing error messages
I am following the tutorial in Chapter 20 of The Rust Programming Language. The sample code doesn't work in my environment, I'm guessing due to differences in browser or OS.
Tutorial here:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html
When I run this code and visit http://localhost:7878 from Chrome, it panics immediately because it unwraps some invalid UTF-8.
use std::{
    io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
    net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
};

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        handle_connection(stream);
    }
}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
    let http_request: Vec<_> = buf_reader
        .lines()
        .map(|result| result.unwrap())
        .take_while(|line| !line.is_empty())
        .collect();

    println!("Request: {:#?}", http_request);
}

But, when a run this code which I have altered to handle the potential non-UTF-8 error, nothing is printed on screen at all. I would expect to see at least the error message.
...

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
    let http_request: Vec<_> = buf_reader
        .lines()
        .map(|result| match result {
            Ok(line) => line,
            Err(err) => err.to_string(),
        })
        .take_while(|line| !line.is_empty())
        .collect();

    println!("Request: {:#?}", http_request);
}


My understanding of this code is that http_request ends up being a Vec<String> of the lines of HyperText of the request, including any error messages.
I have tested (failed) with the .take_while remmed out.
I know I can use .filter_map but I'm more interested to understand why I would not see at least an error message.
Potentially, the .take_while never encounters an empty line and perhaps the lines never end and perhaps .collect never returns?? I'd expect .lines to end at some point though.
Thanks

Please add a [mre] this does add an error on invalid UTF-8 received

How do you send data to your server? One way to ensure that collect returns is to have your client close the connection, which will stop the iteration even if there was never an empty line before.

Hey, thanks for stopping by. The Rust book says to just open a browser to 127.0.0.1:7878 and it'll begin receiving HTTP request messages which, in the book sample output, is as you'd expect GET / HTTP... etc

@cafce25 It now works. I'll explain in my answer.

Great, while you're at it, please add the necessary details to the question and also please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

My altered code with the match does work. Here's what happened.
After reading the comments, I thought the only thing that's a little different is that in my Chrome tab I was entering http://localhost:7878 and not the IP address. So I tried with the IP address...
This led to a bunch of errors coming up the screen, i.e. my match code was working! But this didn't make any sense, because it was the same panic message I got from localhost. Why would the Rust code only work when using localhost?
This led me to think that two things were conspiring to ruin my afternoon:

Chrome was acting a little differently with the IP address
I think either Rust or the TCP stack has buffering and when using localhost the test program was never getting enough data to flush a full chunk through.

So using Chrome with the IP sent enough data for it to flush the errors to the screen.
Anyway, even weirder is that since "flushing out" all the non-UTF-8 data that I was receiving, the program now prints full HTTP requests to the screen, no matter whether I use the IP address or localhost.
No more stream did not contain valid UTF-8 errors at all!
